# convert plaintext to html on PHP

Tags: php, html, yii

I'm using a php frameworks based on (Yii) , my problem is when I insert an html code to my input text after submit I get a plaintext but i want to get is the html format

example

```
<a href="https://example.com/test1"><img src="https://example.com/ex1/ex1.jpg" border="0"></a> <a href="https://example.com/test2"><img src="https://example.com/ex2/ex2.jpg" border="0"></a>
```

---

What I get is text with link to the images

```
<a href="https://example.com/test1"><img src="https://example.com/ex1/ex1.jpg" border="0"></a> <a href="https://example.com/test2"><img src="https://example.com/ex2/ex2.jpg" border="0"></a>
```

my desired output is images not text with link, I used

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities($content)); // not working
html_entity_decode($content); // not working
htmlspecialchars_decode($content); // not working too
nl2br($content); // also not working
```

the output is in the variable content

```
<div class="content" id="wall_content_<?= $object->getUniqueId(); ?>">
                <?= $content; ?> </div>
```

THANK YOU

Comment: So you are doing form submit?

Comment: Please provide more informations like what framework you are using (I can see Yii in the tags?) and the piece of code which generates the HTML.

Comment: what is your desired output look alike? any example?

Comment: Have you tried `htmlentities($content)` to convert all HTML to plain text that HTML parser ignores?

Comment: I'm using humhub (Yii)